# Finding two patterns in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm kind of new to regular expression.

I want to find all the tags that have src, and href in a Html page. I have found this and they are working separately, but not together.

```
string pattern = "<(?:[^>]*?\\s+)?src=([\"'])(.*?)\\1|<(?:[^>]*?\\s+)?href=([\"'])(.*?)\\1";
```

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, because they contain backreferences. Change the last `\\1` to `\\3`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse HTML in C#, you should use a HTML parser, like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

As for "combining" 2 patterns with capturing groups and backreferences, you should always remember that the capturing groups are numbered from left to right regardless of alternation operators, so, in your pattern, there are 4 capturing groups (with `ID` = 1, 2, 3, 4), thus, you need to replace `\\1` with `\\3`.